# Using subdomain gives error in android

Tags: android, json, android-internet

I am having trouble with accessing my `JSON` in android file which is located at [this](http://umsjitm.cutm.org/GreycellsRestAPI/1/loadStudCompList?callback=listStudCompList&currentWingOid=3) website. I am getting an error message `java.net.UnknownHostException: umsjitm.cutm.org`. This is my code:

```
HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
URI website = new URI("http://umsjitm.cutm.org/GreycellsRestAPI /1/loadStudCompList?callback=listStudCompList&currentWingOid=3");
HttpGet request = new HttpGet();
request.setURI(website);
HttpResponse response = client.execute(request);
```

What is wrong with my code?

If I use `http://117.240.237.10/GreycellsRestAPI/1/loadStudCompList?callback=listStudCompList&currentWingOid=1` link, it is working perfectly. Please tell me what am I missing?

Comment: first, remove the space: .../GreycellsRestAPI {here} /1... Are you sure the link works?

Comment: umsjitm.cutm.ort is 117.240.237.7 and not 117.240.237.10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem doesn't seem to be with Android. A ping to `umsjitm.cutm.org` resolves to `117.240.237.7`

Clicking on the link gives a 404 to me.

Also, i don't see a `CNAME` entry to `117.240.237.10` in the [DNS Records](http://who.is/dns/cutm.org) for `umsjitm.cutm.org`

Comment: we have `cutm.org` is located at 117.240.237.7 and umsjitm.cutm.org is located at that given IP only

Comment: http://docs.cpanel.net/twiki/bin/view/AllDocumentation/WHMDocs/DedicatedSubdomains

Comment: As i said, just add a CNAME entry for umsjitm.cutm.org to point to 117.240.237.10

Answer (score 0):

I think this is more related to a DNS Issue...Check you DNS Settings.
Are you sure you can reach that address with its name from the phone?